# How do I sync Finder Tags across Macs

Tags: mac, finder, finder-tag

Between an iMac and MacBook Air, I use Finder Tags extensively. Normally, they sync without effort on my part. The Finder Tags are no longer syncing automatically. How can I 'force' synchronization and control that the MacBook Air updates the iMac and not the other way around?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a manually solution: open Finder -> preferences -> Tags. Look at the 'Favorite Tags' part, then you can drag/delete/add tags to your current right click menu (in your current mac)

Answer (score 0):

Logging out of iCloud then logging back in can resolve some of these hiccups in properly syncing settings across devices. It's a pain but might work.